# How do I update a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, sorting, loops, dictionary

I have used the code:

```
dict1={}
f=open("Class1.txt")
for line in iter(f):
    line=line.split()
    print(line)
    dict1={(line[0]):(line[1])}
    print (dict1)
```

I want to be able to update the list rather than replace the values that are in it as this code is currently doing by looping. I have tried to use .update() but it has not worked.

Comment: What do you mean by "update the list"? What, in your eyes, is the difference between "updating the list" and "replacing the values"?

Comment: that is a dict not a list

Comment: How about `dict1.update({line[0]: line[1]})`?

Comment: you don't need iter either, the file object returns it's own iterator, you would also want to make sure your file is delimited by whitespace and always has at least two elements per line.

Answer (score 2):

The code is almost ok... you need just the small change

```
dict1[line[0]] = line[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

While not entirely clear from your question, I think using a `collections.defaultdict` would do what you want (update the list associated with each dictionary entry):

```
from collections import defaultdict

dict1=defaultdict(list)
f=open("Class1.txt")
for line in iter(f):
    line=line.split()
    print(line)
    dict1[line[0]].append(line[1])
    print (dict1)
```

Comment: I think you can remove the `iter(f)` and maybe using `with` would be better

Comment: @Padraic: Agreed — both could/should be done, but I didn't bother fixing everything and made only minimal changes to the OP's code, since I'm unsure of what's being asked.

Comment: I agree with the defaultdict it was the first thing I thought of when I saw the code, I have just never seen iter called in an iterator!

Comment: @Padraic: It's redundant in this case, but largely harmless (just like not closing the file). The only time you might intentionally want to do such a thing—call `iter()` on an iterator—would be to avoid exhausting the original since they can only be gone over once.